# PHP MongoDB Driver selecting secondary instead of primary mongo db node intermittently

Tags: php, mongodb

I have simple setup with two mongo db nodes (Node A and B). These nodes are also running apache server having php rest api code.

Below are the two scenarios and 2nd is giving problems.

Scenario 1:

```
1) Node A is mongodb primary and Node B mongodb secondary. 
2) REST request sent to Node A, sucessfully processed.
```

Scenario 2:

```
1) Node A is mongodb primary and Node B mongodb secondary. 
2) REST request sent to Node B, request is processed intermittently.
```

Scenario 2 logs:

```
PHP Notice:  REPLSET INFO: pick server: random element 0 in /var/www/html/api/lib/mongo.php on line 396
PHP Notice:  REPLSET INFO: - connection: type: SECONDARY, socket: 42, ping: 0, hash: secondary.host:27017;-;.;27676 in /var/www/html/api/lib/test.php on line 396
PHP Notice:  IO      FINE: getting reply in /var/www/html/api/lib/test.php on line 396
PHP Notice:  IO      FINE: getting cursor header in /var/www/html/api/lib/test.php on line 396
PHP Notice:  CON     FINE: No timeout changes for secondary.host:27017;-;.;27676 in /var/www/html/api/lib/test.php on line 396
PHP Notice:  IO      FINE: getting cursor body in /var/www/html/api/lib/test.php on line 396
PHP Notice:  CON     FINE: No timeout changes for secondary.host:27017;-;.;27676 in /var/www/html/api/lib/test.php on line 396
PHP Notice:  CON     FINE: mongo_connection_destroy: Destroying connection object for secondary.host:27017;-;.;27676 in /var/www/html/api/lib/test.php on line 396
PHP Notice:  CON     FINE: mongo_connection_destroy: Closing socket for secondary.host:27017;-;.;27676. in /var/www/html/api/lib/test.php on line 396
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'MongoCursorException' with message 'secondary.host:27017: not master and slaveOk=false'
```

For scenario 2, it should always select node A but sometimes it choose node B and fails.

PHP code :

```
$this->mongo = new \MongoClient ( $list_of_servers, array ('replicaSet' => 'rs0') );
```

Do I have to make some configuration changes? How to fix this issue?

Thanks

Other information :

```
MongoDB Version -> 3.0.6
PHP MongoDB Driver -> 1.6.9
PHP version -> 5.3.3
OS -> RedHat
```

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/read-preference/

Comment: Thanks for the link. But I think the issue here is different.

Comment: I honestly doubt that. The driver will not change to secondaries with the appropriate read preferences set.

Comment: Did you ever solved this? Im getting the same behaviour

Comment: Not sure whether its right solution but it worked for me. I used Connection Configuration parameter "connectTimeoutMS".  

Why:  

MongoDB driver default behavior is to connect list of servers irrespective of primary or secondary (I had two servers) and default value of connectTimeoutMS is never timeout.   

Primary node gets connected immediately but because of default behavior tries to connect secondary which should fail and was failing but taking time as connectTimeoutMS was not used.  

Hope it helps.